# How to prove $a=b$ when $a\neq b$ and $a$ and $b$ are constants using some tricks?

Tags: proof-writing, fake-proofs

I saw some tricks which proved for example that $1=2$ or $n=n+1$ which is totally non-sense but the error is very well masked in the "proof" that it is almost unnoticeable.

How can I prove any number equal to any other number for example $0.8=1.7$ by using unnoticeable tricks that seem believable?

Can it work for irrational numbers or complex numbers for example ${\sqrt[3]{5}}=0.4$ or $6+i=3$ ?

Comment: These "tricks" usually involve one of two things: (a) dividing by $0$ in a way that is not obvious, or (b) using some "mathematical identity" that does not actually apply (e.g. $1=\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=i \cdot i = -1$). If you use one of these tricks, you've introduced a false statement into your "proof," and from that you could theoretically prove anything.

Comment: I would say that this really depends on exactly what you want to prove and who you want to fool. edit: above comment sums it up pretty well though =).

Comment: Hard to provide a better answer than kccu's... If you start from the false statement $1=2$, then $0=1$ and $2\times 8 +1  = 1\times 8 +0$, divide by ten and you get $0.8=1.7$.

Comment: I also know there's a neat trick that you can pick two constants $a$ and $b$ and put them into $(x-a)(x-b)=0$. For example $3$ and $4$. Then expand into $x^2-7x+12$. Then add (7x-12) to both sides to get $x^2=7x-12$. Now divide both sides by $x$ to get $x={\frac{7x-12}{x}}$. Now you can make a continued fraction by plugging in ${\frac{7x-12}{x}}$ for $x$ that is inside the ${\frac{7x-12}{x}}$ expression itself. Depending on where you stop, you get either 3 or 4, but this way is not really convicing and suspicious to most people.